# When my certificate expires, can I renew the certificate without republishing the application?

Tags: certificate, clickonce, code-signing

I've visited http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx and it is strongly implied that if you need to renew your code signing certificate, then you will need to re-sign your application and re-publish it.  There is no change that happens to the certificate from the side of the CA that extends the lifetime of the certificate.  Is this correct?

Comment: To add to the question: Is the re-sign and re-publish step able to simply done using MageUI? Do you need to increment the version number as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There is no change that happens to the certificate from the side of the CA that
extends the lifetime of the certificate. Is this correct?
```

No.

The validity dates are included in the certificate, so a certificate with a new expiration date is different than your currently expiring one.